# sql: how to add a constraint about 'always contains something'

Tags: sql-server

I just wanted to know, how to write the constraint on sql server, where it should always contain a `'@'` sign and a `'.'`. Should I use check or what? It's about an email actually.

Comment: It is a UI validation not a DB validation

Comment: @techspider it could be done as a constraint on the DB too. Personally I prefer data constraints at the DB level to protect my data as much as possible.

Comment: @SeanLange - Yes, It can be!! But, I somehow hesitate on placing data validations on constraints. If I'm not providing a valid email, why should my request all the way go to DB?  it could be caught by simple JavaScript validation.  I understand your point of having someone trying to insert into DB.  But, if we go by that rule, we may end up duplicating every validation in DB constraints.

Comment: As somebody responsible for the data I don't put much faith the front end. Also, there are more ways than the front end that data can enter the database. If the constraint is at the database level then somebody can't accidentally enter invalid data with a query in SSMS. And what happens when the front end changes? Now you either have no validation or you have to write it again.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `CHECK` constraint like this

Using `LIKE` operator

```
ALTER TABLE Yourtable ADD CHECK (email_col like '%@%.%')
```

Using `CHARINDEX` function

```
ALTER TABLE Yourtable 
  ADD CHECK (Charindex('@',email_col)>0 AND Charindex('.', email_col, Charindex('@', email_col)+1 )>0)
```